# Adding a private nameserver to public DNS zone for a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone, azure-dns

We have a DNS zone setup on Azure which resolves all of our records on our base domain (eg: `example.com`). We also have an internal DNS server using BIND and are currently duplicating the records on the public and private DNS.

I am trying to set up the DNS to use the private DNS for subdomain `*.pvt.example.com` and use the public DNS for `*.example.com`

To test this I have created an entry in the main zone file on the private DNS server

```
testhost.pvt IN      A       172.16.17.18
```

On Azure, I have added an NS record for `pvt.example.com` pointing to my private DNS server IP.

I am able to resolve `testhost.pvt.example.com` when using the private DNS, but this does not work from the public DNS.

Is there any other network setting that needs to be done? (The private DNS is not accessible from the internet)

Comment: NS records take names, not IPs, and if your private DNS server isn't accessible from the Internet, how do you expect public DNS resolution attempts to work?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I guess I don't understand DNS resolution very well, I think for now ill go with using duplicate entries on my private and public DNS

Answer (score 0):

We have similar situation where public IP was different from internal IP. To reconcile, we've created local zone that doesn't copy all records but created only those that differ for easy maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if something similar to this is possible for me.